# In biblatex, style=verbose kills \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex

I want to combine both verbose footnote citations (e.g. `style=verbose`) and a complete list of all bibliography items (with `\printbibliography`). As it turns out, it doesn't work. This is entirely puzzling for me, since I would expect this to be a pretty standard combination.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
  style=verbose, % #1: works without this line
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography_mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
This is only a test! \footcite{TestArticle}
\appendix
\printbibliography % #2: works without this line
\end{document}

% does not work if both line #1 and #2 are included
```

and, for completeness, my `bibliography_mwe.bib`:

```
@article{TestArticle,
  author = {John Doe},
  journal = {Latex Discoveries},
  title = {How to set up Biblatex},
  year = {2014}
}
```

If I run this, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bibhang
```

And some more errors that follow from this.

If I comment out line `#1`, there is no error, but I only get numeric citations. If I comment out line `#2`, there is no error, but I don't get a bibliography, obviously.

What is going on here? What am I doing wrong? This is such a simple setup, I must be overlooking something obvious.

---

Edit: This is the file list produced by the `\listfiles` command:

```
*File List*
scrreprt.cls    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
biblatex.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)

etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
verbose.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_.def    
standard.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authortitle.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
verbose.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
verbose.cbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
english.lbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_mwe.bbl
***********
```

`biber --version` > `biber version: 2.4`

`lsb_release -d` > `Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`

I am using the latest texlive 2015, upgraded from an manual texlive 2014 installation (not the one in the Ubuntu repositories).

---

I added the [log file](https://gist.github.com/eklenske/4e06ab30156f11c669e1825877983908) of one run. The full error message is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bibhang 

l.13 \end
        {document}
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                \relax 
l.13 \end
        {document}
? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                \relax 
l.13 \end
        {document}
?
```

Comment: You can find the version number of each in the logs produced.

Comment: Mhhh, this looks like a very odd error to me. Please make sure that your version of `biblatex` is up to date. You can check the versions very comfortably by adding `\listfiles` to the very beginning of your MWE file, after a compilation (just force through the errors) you will find a nicely formatted list of the versions used at the end of the`.log` file, post that here.

Comment: Mhhh, those versions are not the newest, but they don't look horribly outdated either. Try to delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) and compile your MWE again. If the error still isn't gone show us the relevant parts of the log (entire error message etc.).

Comment: Any news here? Can you give us the full error message?

Comment: I added the full error message and a log file. But I guess I'll have to use texlive 2016 to solve the problem. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of sad, but it seems like some weird condition, buried within the arcane maze of texlive internals, caused this problem.

The following hack provides a quick workaround:

```
\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{5mm}
```

But ultimately, I don't see a solution other than installing texlive 2016 after all.

Thanks for all the helpful comments!

---

As suggested in the comments, I upgraded to texlive 2016. The MWE works without any issues. Apparently, the combination of verbose-style citations and full bibliography in the end is broken in texlive 2015.

Comment: It wasn't broken for me in older versions of `biblatex` (I don't use TeX live, but MikTeX). But I guess it is hard to find out what caused the problem now.

Comment: It doesn't work for me . https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405708/documentstyle-with-printbibliography