# documentstyle with printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Works(printbiblography outputs in the pdf):

```
\RequirePackage{biblatex}
\documentstyle{article}
\addbibresource{publs.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{bhatia2014genetically}
asdf
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Works(printbiblography does NOT output in the pdf)

```
\RequirePackage{biblatex}
\documentstyle{res_yy}
\addbibresource{publs.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{bhatia2014genetically}
asdf
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Using the format from here http://www.yisongyue.com/resume/
printbiblograhy does nothing in this case.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  are you seriously using `\]documentstyle`?  that's latex 2.09 syntax.  it's been out of date since 1995.  `\documentclass` is the current equivalent.  i wouldn't expect any of this to work properly with `\documentstyle`.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [*.aux file not generated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27139/35864). `yy_res.cls` is based on `res.cls` and also uses `\nofiles`, but `biblatex` needs auxiliary files.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am using the format here http://www.yisongyue.com/resume/. Is there a direct way to convert the .sty file?

Comment: @moewe how can I modify the res.cls class? I am only using yy_res.cls

Comment: What about adding `\let\nofiles\relax` before `\documentstyle{res_yy}` as suggested in the linked answer? Of course the real answer is not to use `res_yy`.

Comment: @moewe that doesn't work, any alternative way to print biblography?

Comment: Do you really have to use this totally outdated class? It uses LaTeX 2.09 syntax that has been outdated for more than 20 years now. See also the notice on the page you link to 'This template is provided "as is" and is no longer actively maintained. Systems using newer versions of LaTeX might have some compatibility issues with this template.'

Answer (score 3):

`res_yy.sty` is based on [`res`](https://ctan.org/pkg/res) and issues

```
\nofiles         % resume's don't need .aux files
```

See also [*.aux file not generated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27139/35864)

Apparently, the assumption `resume's don't need .aux files` is wrong, since you want a bibliography and bibliographies often rely on auxiliary files.

You should look into different, more modern document classes for a resume.  `\documentstyle` is old LaTeX 2.09 syntax that has been outdated for more than twenty years now. http://www.yisongyue.com/resume/ even mentions

> **NOTE** - This template is provided "as is" and is no longer actively maintained. Systems using newer versions of LaTeX might have some compatibility issues with this template.

So you really should not expect this class to work properly any more with a modern package like `biblatex` (`biblatex` is a good 15 years younger than LaTeX2e, the successor of LaTeX 2.09). In fact if you run your MWE on a modern TeX distribution you get quite prominent warnings

> ```
>          Entering LaTeX 2.09 COMPATIBILITY MODE
> *************************************************************
>    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!   
>
> This mode attempts to provide an emulation of the LaTeX 2.09
> author environment so that OLD documents can be successfully
> processed. It should NOT be used for NEW documents!
>
> New documents should use Standard LaTeX conventions and start
> with the \documentclass command.
>
> Compatibility mode is UNLIKELY TO WORK with LaTeX 2.09 style
> files that change any internal macros, especially not with
> those that change the FONT SELECTION or OUTPUT ROUTINES.
>
> Therefore such style files MUST BE UPDATED to use
>          Current Standard LaTeX: LaTeX2e.
> If you suspect that you may be using such a style file, which
> is probably very, very old by now, then you should attempt to
> get it updated by sending a copy of this error message to the
> author of that file.
> *************************************************************
> ```

If you *must* use `res_yy` you will have to modify a local, renamed copy of `res_yy.sty` yourself since `\let\nofiles\relax` before `\documentstyle` does not work.

Rename a copy of `res_yy.sty` to `res_yy_ab.sty`, find the `\nofiles` statement and comment the entire line by placing a `%` before it.

Then modify your file to load `\documentstyle{res_yy_ab}`.

But really the answer is to not use this document style.