# How can I get my CV to print the publication list?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cv

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[margin]{res}
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs1.bib}
@inproceedings{McGoldrick:2016:WCR:2999504.3001118,
    author = {Mc Goldrick, Ciar\'{a}n and Segura, Enrique and Wu, Tianyan and Gerla, Mario},
    title = {WaterCom: Connecting Research Configurations with Practical Deployments: A Multilevel, Multipurpose Underwater Communications Test Platform},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 11th ACM International Conference on Underwater Networks \& Systems},
    series = {WUWNet '16},
    year = {2016},
    isbn = {978-1-4503-4637-5},
    location = {Shanghai, China},
    pages = {8:1--8:2},
    articleno = {8},
    numpages = {2},
    url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2999504.3001118},
    doi = {10.1145/2999504.3001118},
    acmid = {3001118},
    publisher = {ACM},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
}

@inproceedings{Goldrick:2015:WMM:2831296.2831336,
    author = {Goldrick, Ciar\'{a}n Mc and Matney, Mark and Segura, Enrique and Noh, Youngtae and Gerla, Mario},
    title = {WaterCom: A Multilevel, Multipurpose Underwater Communications Test Platform},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 10th International Conference on Underwater Networks \& Systems},
    series = {WUWNET '15},
    year = {2015},
    isbn = {978-1-4503-4036-6},
    location = {Arlington, VA, USA},
    pages = {14:1--14:8},
    articleno = {14},
    numpages = {8},
    url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2831296.2831336},
    doi = {10.1145/2831296.2831336},
    acmid = {2831336},
    publisher = {ACM},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs1.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}
\section{PUBLICATIONS}
\printbibliography{refs1}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you do the normal cycle `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                sample
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

That's what I get on the first pdflatex.

On Biber, I get this: 

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'sample.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?

Comment: You can't use `bibentry` with `biblatex`.  Use proper `biblatex` methods for doing this sort of thing. See e.g. [biblatex: List of publications in the CV](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/115143)

Comment: Anyway, biber is the default engine for bib latex. I tested, and can't obtain a bibliography with this class. However, it works fine with a standard class like `article`. Could you consider changing class?

Comment: Will that affect my resume format then?

Comment: I still get the empty bibliography statement.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27139/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405708/35864

Answer (score 3):

The `res.cls` blocks the use of any `.aux` files by issuing a `\nofiles` command inside the class.  This means that out of the box you cannot use *any* bibliography software with it.

I would probably recommend using a different class altogether, or just formatting your CV using `article` and a few packages. But if you do want to continue to use the `res.cls` it can be done.

### Edit `res.cls`

Make a copy of `res.cls` and rename it, e.g. `res-bib.cls`.  Line 203 of the class ([version on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/res?lang=en)) should read:

```
\nofiles %  resume's don't need .aux files
```

Delete or comment this line out in the copy of your class. (Deleting is preferred since it  will also get rid of the apostrophe in the comment...)

### Use `biblatex` not `bibentry`

Now, using the modified class, here's how to use `biblatex` to add the publications:

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[margin]{res-bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{McGoldrick:2016:WCR:2999504.3001118,
    author = {Mc Goldrick, Ciar\'{a}n and Segura, Enrique and Wu, Tianyan and Gerla, Mario},
    title = {WaterCom: Connecting Research Configurations with Practical Deployments: A Multilevel, Multipurpose Underwater Communications Test Platform},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 11th ACM International Conference on Underwater Networks \& Systems},
    series = {WUWNet '16},
    year = {2016},
    isbn = {978-1-4503-4637-5},
    location = {Shanghai, China},
    pages = {8:1--8:2},
    articleno = {8},
    numpages = {2},
    url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2999504.3001118},
    doi = {10.1145/2999504.3001118},
    acmid = {3001118},
    publisher = {ACM},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
}

@inproceedings{Goldrick:2015:WMM:2831296.2831336,
    author = {Goldrick, Ciar\'{a}n Mc and Matney, Mark and Segura, Enrique and Noh, Youngtae and Gerla, Mario},
    title = {WaterCom: A Multilevel, Multipurpose Underwater Communications Test Platform},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 10th International Conference on Underwater Networks \& Systems},
    series = {WUWNET '15},
    year = {2015},
    isbn = {978-1-4503-4036-6},
    location = {Arlington, VA, USA},
    pages = {14:1--14:8},
    articleno = {14},
    numpages = {8},
    url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2831296.2831336},
    doi = {10.1145/2831296.2831336},
    acmid = {2831336},
    publisher = {ACM},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\begin{resume}

% we need heading=bibnumbered here to tell biblatex to use \section 
% not \section* (which will produce a spurious * with this class)
%
\printbibliography[title=PUBLICATIONS,heading=bibnumbered]


\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Hi, I still can't get into work; can't find the res-bib.cls ?

Comment: @EnriqueSegura Make a copy of `res.cls` and rename it `res-bib.cls`, then make the edit described in the answer.

Comment: and what compilation is the one you used?

Comment: I did that; copy the res file, edit the line. still didn't work.

Comment: my problem is that, even for this example, the bibliography after the changes in the .cls file is still empty.

Comment: Are you compiling with `pdftlatex` then `biber` then `pdflatex` (twice)?

Comment: Yes. I did get sample working, but not the overall file.

Comment: @EnriqueSegura Did you change the `\addbibresource` line to point to your actual `bib` file? Did you remember the `\nocite{*}` in the document?